# How to create part of an object a separate object on Blender?

Tags: python, blender

I am creating a figure on Blender and I do not know how to take a part of the object and turn it into a separate object. Below is a picture- the area in orange is what I want to create as a separate object from the rest of the object.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While in edit mode press <kbd>P</kbd> and choose Selection. This is also available in the Mesh menu under Vertices->Separate.

[image]

You may also want to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> to duplicate the selection before separating if you don't want to remove the part from the current mesh.

Also Blender has it's own site at [blender.stackexchange.com](http://blender.stackexchange.com) for blender specific help.